# Scraping stock price data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the prices from this URL.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

https://stockcharts.com/h-hd/?%24GSPCE

```
        resp = requests.get(BASE_URL).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
        prices = soup.find('div', {'class': 'historical-data-descrip'})
        
        content = str(prices)
        print(content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stockcharts only provides historical data to StockChart members, so you probably need to pass some kind of authentication.

Or use an api like [this one](https://www.yahoofinanceapi.com/)

Comment: You're right. I am a subscriber but didn't realise that page was only for subscribers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> You must be logged in to your StockCharts.com account to see this information.

are you signed in on your browser?

get the soup.contents() and open them in a notepad document and search for the above to see if you're straight up getting a login error